# How to install pandas 0.20.0

Tags: python, pandas, pip

I know that in Pandas v0.20.0, df.to_excel introduced a "freeze_panes" variable. However, I cannot seem to get it working. I've upgraded Pandas via Pip to the most recent version but I'm still getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    mergeda.to_excel(writer, 'Results 1', index=False, 
freeze_panes=[1,1])
TypeError: to_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'freeze_panes'
```

Whenever I find my version of Pandas, however, I get this:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.__version__
'0.16.1'
```

I've tried pip uninstall pandas and then pip install pandas/pip install --upgrade pandas but it seems to be holding on to this old version no matter what. I'm just trying to freeze the first column and/or row.

Comment: Are you trying to do this from the shell or within a jupyter notebook? Are you using conda to manage your packages? or just pip with the system python?

Comment: Just in the shell for now. I've got a df.to_excel() line in my code that works properly but I'm trying to add to it. Just pip is managing my packages. I've got Python installed via ArcGIS.

Comment: Try pip install -Iv <pkg name>==<version>.   It will ignore previous version and install the desired version.

Comment: Still nothing. Even when I force it to install 0.20.1 it still brings up 0.16.1 as the installed version.

Comment: Try the following: 1) type "which python" to see where your python is installed, 2) type "which pip" and see where that is, 3) within python, import pandas as pd and type pd.__file__, and 4) import sys and use sys.path to see where python is searching for packages. Once you know where pandas and pip are relative to your python installation, you can go from there. If you're able to, using conda to manage environments and packages could be the most robust and pain-free solution long-term.

Comment: You have an environment problem where the python executed when you run `pip` is different from the one when you run `python`.

Comment: So it looks like I have Pandas 0.16.1 installed in the Python folder in my ArcGISx64 installation directory. But the newest version of Pandas is installed in my x86 version. In my environment variables I have my Path set to the x86 version. But I am using the x64 version of Python. Should I change some of this? Or should I install pip in the x64 folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I'm sure there was a different way but since I have three versions of Python installed (2.7x86, 2.7x64, 3.5) I uninstalled pip and removed the pip folders from site-packages in each directory. Set my PATH to the x64 version of Python and reinstalled pip there. Pandas installs fine now.